# I typed 'php artisan migrate' in cmd then it shows me error

Tags: php, laravel

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = cvs and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

at C:\xampp\htdocs\cvs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
670|        ``` catch (Exception $e) {

> 671|             throw new QueryException(
> 672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 673|             );
> 674|         }```
> 675|

1   C:\xampp\htdocs\cvs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
PDOException::("could not find driver")

2   C:\xampp\htdocs\cvs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
PDO::__construct()

Comment: check your .env file. Does it have correct credentials ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable php_mysqli in the php.ini file?

Look for this line in php.ini file and make sure it is uncommented.

```
extension=php_mysqli.so
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually problem that the DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD credentials are wrong.

It is also necessary to verify that the bd engine driver is activated.

[PDO MySQL Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoLWH.png)

[phpinfo() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V7hb.png)